# What is the minimum drill voltage/power required for a plumbing snake bit?

Tags: plumbing, tools

In particular this one [Cobra Products 25Ft Power Drain Snake](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H5SJQ0).

[image]

Will a 12-volt cordless be strong enough?

Comment: You could try contacting [Customer Service](http://www.cobraus.com/faq.asp), and asking what type of drill they recommend.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the size/strength of the clog.

However, as an owner of a Hitachi 12v cordless, I find it quite strong as long as the charge is good, so probably.

Answer (score 1):

According to customer service for this manufacturer, yes, 12v is fine.

YMMV for other comparable products

Comment: Did you call customer service, or were you able to find this information online?

Comment: Called cust service - funny enough, they said I was the first person to call in with that question. They actually took down my number and got back to me, so thumbs up on that manufacturer for going above and beyond on a ten-dollar item.

Comment: The customer service rep was probably super stoked to actually talk to somebody, you helped him meet his quota of 1 call/year.  Although, you probably interrupted Angry Birds.